# Cannot fig out error in my gradient function implementation in python

Tags: python, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

Im trying to implement following gradient descent function in Python for logistic regression:

$∇θ(−logL)=−X^T (y−e^{Xθ})$

This is my python implementation:

```py
def gradient(X, y, theta):
    dtheta = -(np.dot(X.T,y - np.exp(X * theta)))
    return dtheta
```

`X` is a dataframe of size: (2458, 31), 
`y` is a dataframe of size: (2458, 1)
`theta` is dataframe of size: (2458,1)

when i pass values to my gradient descent function, it returns a `dtheta` parameter with size (31,31) due to which i cannot update my theta to pass it to cost function, i cannot fig out where im going wrong.
any help will be appreciated.

Error i keep getting is: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2458,1) (31,31)`

and this is how im implementing the algorithm:

```py
theta = np.random.uniform(low=-0.1,high=0.1, size=(2458,1))
# Iterate and update theta by using the gradient of the negative log-likelihood
max_iter = 100
learning_rate = 1e-3
for i in range(max_iter):
    # Calculate the gradient
    dtheta = gradient(X,y,theta)

    # Update theta

    theta = (theta - learning_rate) * dtheta

    # Calculate the value of the log-likelihood
    cost = negative_loglikelihood(X,y,theta)

    # Print iteration
    print("Iteration %d, cost function %.3f" % (i+1,cost))
```

Comment: Can you share the source of the above gradient descent formula?

Comment: This is part of an assignment that i received, in which i have a negative log likelihood function whose gradient function is as above.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `theta` dimensions.

Most likely, your `X` dimensions indicate you have `2458` training samples per iteration with each having `31` features. Hence, your `theta` should be a matrix of shape `(31, 1)`.

With `X` having shape `(2458, 31)` and if `theta` has shape `(31, 1)`, `X*theta` will have dimensions `(2458, 1)`, same as `y` and as expected. Now, `y-theta` has the same dimensions as that of `y` or `theta`. And so does `exp(y-theta)`

`X_T` has shape `(31, 2458)` and hence, `d_theta = - X_T*exp(y-theta)` will have shape `(31, 1)`, same as our initial assumed `theta` shape and now, you can subtract `d_theta` from `theta`.

Comment: Thank you very much,  that seems to have solved the issue. Though now im facing the similar issue in implementing my neg. log likelihood function,I may have implemented it wrong,

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting the answer :)